# Creating a sorted array from a string and an array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a sorted array but im having trouble understanding how I would created it. 
I have a string (s1) and another array (a1,a2,a3,....).

I want to create a new array using the string and array. I would like to put them in this order (s1 - ar - s1 - ar - s1 -ar).

*ar = the original array in a random order.

How would I go about that creating this array?

Thanks for any help

*Edit: I would like a shuffled array having s1 string at every alternate index

Comment: i can't undersatnd ur question...u mean u need to short string array??

Comment: Even I don't understand what you want, I'm not surprised you don't either.

Comment: I have edited it to try and make it clearer

Comment: how many time u want to create this type or sorting ????

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate each time s1 ?
Otherwise, you could use `insertObject:AtIndex` in a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: this question is very ambiguous. :(

Comment: Its going to be an array of images urls. I want every other image url to be the s1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up shuffling the array and adding the string to every even index.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a1", @"a2", @"a3", @"a4", @"a5",nil];

[array shuffle];
for (int i = 0 ; i<array.count; i=i+2) {
    [array insertObject:@"s1" atIndex:i];
}

NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

This is how I shuffled the array

```
NSMutableArray+Shuffling.h

    @interface NSMutableArray (Shuffling)
    - (void)shuffle;
    @end 


NSMutableArray+Shuffling.m
#import "NSMutableArray+Shuffling.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffling)

- (void)shuffle
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < self.count; ++i)
    {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        int nElements = self.count - i;
        int n = arc4random_uniform(nElements) + i;
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
}
@end
```

This I what the output looked like 
Array (s1,
    a3,
    s1,
    a5,
    s1,
    a4,
    s1,
    a2,
    s1,
    a1)

Sorry If the question was poorly worded.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand is correctly you need to create a new array and then one by one fill it up. So like insert the string then take a random element from the array till you run out of elements.

If you want to modify the original array then it has to be mutable (what language are you using?)

in objective-c it would be something like this:

```
NSString* string;

NSArray* array;

NSMutableArray* temparray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

NSMutableArray* result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]*2];

for (int i=0; i< [array count];i++) {
    [result addObject:string];
    int index = rand() % [temparray count];
    [result addObject:[temparray objectAtIndex:index]];
    [temparray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: then use NSMutableArray to arrange the items. It is not hard, do you need code, or..?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**NSMutableArray**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a1", @"a2", @"a3",nil];
[array insertObject:@"s1" atIndex:0]; // add as first object
[array addObject:@"s2"]; // add as last object
 // sort
[array sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

// swap elements
[array exchangeObjectAtIndex:1 withObjectAtIndex:2];

for (NSString *s in array)
{
    NSLog(@"elemnt: %@", s);
}
```